# React tutorial not loading base.css

Tags: css, reactjs

I am having trouble with the React tutorial. After some help from stackoverflow I was able to get the server/API running, but now for some strange reason base.css is not loading.

base.css is in the css folder where it should be, and when I'm editing in Dreamweaver it automatically loads base.css just fine, so I'm really confused.

[image]

Here is my index.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>React Tutorial</title>
        <!-- Not present in the tutorial. Just for basic styling. -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.15/browser.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.5/marked.min.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <script type="text/babel">

        var Comment = React.createClass({
            render: function() {
                return (
                    <div className="comment">
                        <h2 className="commentAuthor">
                            {this.props.author}
                        </h2>
                            {this.props.children}
                    </div>
                )
            }
        });

          var CommentList = React.createClass({
              render: function() {
                return (
                  <div className="commentList">
                    <Comment author="Pete Hunt"> This is one comment</Comment>
                    <Comment author="Jordan Walke"> This is another comment</Comment>
                  </div>
                );
              }
            });

            var CommentForm = React.createClass({
              render: function() {
                return (
                  <div className="commentForm">
                    Hello, world! I am a CommentForm.
                  </div>
                );
              }
            });

          var CommentBox = React.createClass({
          render: function() {
            return (
              <div className="commentBox">
              <h1>Comments</h1>
                <CommentList />
                <CommentForm />
              </div>
            );
          }
        });



        ReactDOM.render(
          <CommentBox />,
          document.getElementById('content')
        );

        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Check base.css line 7 or if you can post base.css file or more info about the error status.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I needed to add a leading slashing to the .css file reference.

became

The css was loaded and applied to the page.